# Can two Python programs write to different sheets in the same .xlsx file simultaneously?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to create two python programs namely A and B. A will access **'test.xlsx'**(excel file), create a sheet called **'sheet1'** and write to **'sheet1'**. Python program B will access **'test.xlsx'**(excel file), create a sheet called **'sheet2'** and write to **'sheet2'** simultaneously.
Is it possible to do the above process?

Comment: Generally speaking, you can't have two programs writing to the same file simultaneously.

Comment: "Possible"? Sure, it's possible. Build a daemon that's responsible for doing I/O on behalf of both A and B. Or implement locking (_safely_, using `flock` or a third-party tool like [`fasteners`](https://pypi.org/project/fasteners/); don't roll your own on this unless you know where the sharp edges are hidden). To have two processes really doing edits on a file at the same time, that file format needs to be designed to allow that concurrency, and the libraries used to access it need to take advantage of those design features; it's a lot of work.

Comment: Anyhow -- I do think this is potentially an answerable question, but whoever wants to answer it well is going to need to get into implementation details of openpyxl. If each sheet is a different file inside the zip file that is a .xlsx, and there's a locking mechanism for the index of sheets, then maybe this _could_ work if the library is designed to take advantage of those format design details; but that's pure speculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, you have to secure both programs from accessing the file at the same time.
For example, through a lock file.
This mechanism must be on both sides.

```py
import os

from time import sleep
from os import path
# xlsx lib

FILENAME = 'test.xlsx'
LOCK_FILENAME = f'.~{FILENAME}'

while path.exists(LOCK_FILENAME):
    sleep(.1)

with open(LOCK_FILENAME, 'w') as f: ...

# do your code

os.remove(LOCK_FILENAME)
```

Comment: Yes, lockfiles are a reasonable choice, but this isn't a good way to manage them. If the system reboots or your program crashes with the lockfile open, this code leaves it still there; and you have race conditions if something else grabs a lock between the `path.exists` and the `open`.

Comment: Properly, there shouldn't be cases where you need to have access to 1 file from 2 programs. The simplest solution is to create a 3rd program and write to the file through it. 
But if he asked a question like that, he won't do it.

Comment: Eh -- for some file types it's reasonable and appropriate, so I wouldn't say "shouldn't be cases" as a general rule. Look at SQLite, for example, which combines region locking and a transaction log to make concurrent access safe. And it's common to have multiple processes appending to a shared log file when they both have it opened in append mode (where the filesystem enforces that writes don't overlap each other) and are keeping individual log entries short enough to fit in a single `write()` syscall.

Comment: The question here is how well openpyxl and .xlsx are designed to manage concurrency. That's a fact-intensive investigation that calls for someone who knows that library in particular.

Comment: I agree. To paraphrase, in this case there should not be such a situation and if you use improvised mutex, deadlock is a possible situation, and it cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Generally operation of opening a file performed on an object is to associate it to a real file. An open file is represented within a program by a stream and any input or output operation performed on this stream object will be applied to the physical file associated to it.

The act of closing the file (actually, the stream) ends the association; the transaction with the file system is terminated, and input/output may no longer be performed on the stream. Python doesn't flush the buffer—that is, write data to the file—until it's sure you're done writing, and one way to do this is to close the file. If you write to a file without closing, the data won't make it to the target file.

When we are finished with our input and output operations on a file we shall close it so that the operating system is notified and its resources become available again.

There are to ways you can pick, either you open/close file synchronically or you will make a copy of your file and destroy it afterwards.

Comment: This smells like ChatGPT -- lots of text, vaguely on the requested topic but not actually specific enough to let the OP solve their problem, and factually wrong in subtle ways.

Comment: (Python doesn't _guarantee_ that it'll flush content to disk until you close or perform a specific flush, but it also doesn't guarantee that it won't, and that's doubly true for xlsx-writing libraries, which are working with a zip-like format that involves random access and otherwise have a bunch of interesting and relevant details under the hood).